# Moving SWC to libs folder breaks project

Tags: apache-flex, swc, degrafa

I have a swc(degrafa) that I have been referencing externally in another folder on my computer.  When I tried to move the swc to the libs folder I was no longer able to access the swc from my application.  Is there a step im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project libs folder was not the same as the one in the project tree.  This was due to the project i am working on being apart of a larger project and the project properties was referencing the wrong folder.  After changing the libs folder to the one I wanted to use the swc was recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Did you updated your library path as described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html)?

1. With a project selected in the Flex Navigator view, select Project > Properties > Flex Build Path.
2. Click on the Library Path tab, and then select and expand the SWC file entry to display the SWC options.
3. Double-click the Link Type option. The Library Path Items Options dialog box appears.
4. Select the Merged into Code option, and click OK.

This procedure is the equivalent of using the *library-path* compiler option.

Comment: thanks for your time to help me.  For that I will give you +1.  See the answer that I posted.